# EasyGUI buttonbox close button not functioning in version0.96

Tags: python, python-3.x, easygui

I am using `EasyGUI` 0.96.0. In a `buttonbox` I have buttons which invoke their respective functions. But when I try to close the `buttonbox` using the red colored close button in the corner (beside the "maximize" and "minimize" button), It does not work.

Is there any fix available for the problem above?

The code is as follows:

```
from easygui import *  
from tkinter import *

from tkinter import messagebox

top = Tk()
top.geometry("1000x150")
def helloCallBack():
    choices = ["Debashis", "Mandal"]
    reply = buttonbox("This is easygui", title="title",choices=choices, root=top)
    if reply == "Debashis":
        print ("Debashis")
    else:
        sys.exit(1)
B = Button(top, text ="Hello", command = helloCallBack)

B.place(x=50,y=50)

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, meaning I can close the window just fine with the close button provided by the (windowing) system. Can you show some code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: The code is indented. No errors faced due to indentation.

Comment: It's hard to figure out if it's not formatted as expected by Python. And it seems to be wrong: `buttonbox` doesn't expect a `root` argument. This leads to an exception. Also you import `messagebox` but don't use it.

Comment: everything is working fine and as expected; its only that I am unable to close the buttonbox by clicking the "close" button appearing at the corner beside the maximize and minimize button of the buttonbox

Comment: And this is true for even the fileopenbox and codebox also

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replies @BlackJack. I have found a solution to the issue by upgrading to easygui version 0.98.1. Previously I had been using version 0.96.3